# Blackberry - Interrupt outgoing call

Tags: blackberry

I want to stop outgoing call and open the application. The app is able to listen new outgoing call. Now I don’t have any idea how to stop the call and open the app. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pause it, but you can do whatever you want when a call is initiated, by the following code:

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.PhoneListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class CallInterrupting extends Application implements PhoneListener {

    public CallInterrupting() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CallInterrupting().enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public void callAdded(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callConnected(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callHeld(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callInitiated(int callid) {
        // A CALL IS INITIATED HERE, PUT YOUR CODE !
    }

    public void callRemoved(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callResumed(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void callWaiting(int callid) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }
}
```

If you mean to totally cancel/drop the call, set permissions for device as follows:

1. Options
2. Advanced Options
3. Applications
4. APP_NAME
5. Edit Default permissions
6. Interactions
7. key stroke Injection

Then call the following function in the desired catched event:

```
    public void cancellingCall()
    {
        KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
        inject.post();
        // OPEN YOUR APP HERE
    }
```

Comment: i tried the code above on simulator. Simulator shows a dialog box with options like "answer", "fail", etc. But the call does not gets disconnected.

Comment: Did you tried to assert "key stroke Injection" by the steps above and then cancellingCall (as implemented in the answer), by calling it from events mentioned above ?

Comment: thanks. finally got it worked. For opening the app, i am doing UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HelloBlackBerryScreen()); but it goes to background (like it opens and then disappears).

Comment: If the answer helps you and it's the required solution, kindly mark it up and mark it as answer. For another question please open a new discussion post to focus on title topic (for later users searches)

Comment: In your last comment, could you please clarify and give snipshot of the code to detect the problem ?

Comment: Did you tried: UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground(); ?

Comment: surely, i will accept the answer once problem is solved. Here is the code: public void callInitiated(int callid) {
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char)Keypad.KEY_END, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP(char)Keypad.KEY_END,KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressEndKey);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseEndKey);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( new HelloBlackBerryScreen());
}
Anything wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9642/discussion-between-dhairya-vora-and-ashraf-bashir)

Comment: Did you try: UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground(); after pushing the screen ?

Comment: UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground(); opens app if bb os is : 7 but it does not open the app if the os version is 5. Sorry if I am asking too much of help. I am newbie for bb.

Comment: It's in RIM5, check http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#requestForeground() ... And You can call it like this:
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground();
    });
}
Does it throw an exception? Try to enclose the invoke and wait in a try catch and also its content in a try catch, if an exception is catched send it to investigate the issue

Comment: You can also push it as Global screen:  UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushGlobalScreen(new MyScreen(), 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_MODAL); ..... and in your screen override the following method: protected void onObscured(){
 Screen activeScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();  
 activeScreen.getUiEngine().suspendPainting(true);
 UiApplication.getApplication().requestForeground();
} .....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it works fine for me.
On your Outgoing call listener method use this code to disconnect call and after that code open your app.

```
public static void DisconnectCall() 
{


    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() 
        {
            try{
                final EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(
                        KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char)Keypad.KEY_END, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
                final EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(
                        KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, (char)Keypad.KEY_END, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
                EventInjector.invokeEvent (pressEndKey);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                EventInjector.invokeEvent (releaseEndKey);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
```